# NoSQL - difference between key/value NoSQL and Document NoSQL

Tags: mongodb, nosql, amazon-dynamodb

As I understand, DynamoDB uses Key/Value NoSQL and MongoDB uses Document NoSQL. Looking at sample files from each, I am unable to come up with an explanation of what the difference(s) is/are between the two.
I've searched to find anything that elaborates on the differences, without success.

Is there a link that I have missed which might contain the explanation?
OR
Could someone share their insight into this?

Answer (score 0):

In a nutshell: Key/value stores usually have a very limited API. Get/set value by key and that's it (slightly exaggerated). MongoDB, on the other hand, allows much finer operations on individual fields in a document (sees their inner structure rather than treating them as opaque blobs).

Comment: Thanks. Are the Key/Value and Document JSONS interchangeable?

Comment: @AAsk what do you mean "jsons"?

Comment: JSON format - the way the key/value pairs are written in the document.